# Paging library - one recycler with multiple view types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am using all Android architecture components in my project (Room DB, Live Data etc.) Currently, I am facing a problem that I have RecyclerView which should used loaded data from Room DB and display it with Paging library. The problem is that there is a multiple data classes which represents the items in newsfeed and are stored in Room and I need display them in that one recycler.

Is there any way how to easily solve it? Can I for example create some interface which would be used by all these classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create and interface

```
public interface NeewsFeedItem
    String getTitle();
    int getType();
    String data();
...
```

Each of your model `implement NeewsFeedItem` and inside your Adapter you decide what type of view to show and how to show the proper `NeewsFeedItem`.

You could override [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) to show different presentation for different NeewsFeed's types.

Also you could check [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) library that could help to manage your adapter with different types, headers, footers etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide multiple View holder to list by overriding getItemViewType() method of  RecyclerView.Adapter.

**Code Snippet**

```
  @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
    // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
         case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
         ...
     }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 0:
            ViewHolder0 viewHolder0 = (ViewHolder0)holder;
            ...
            break;

        case 2:
            ViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (ViewHolder2)holder;
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

For more detaild please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/5167937) link.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add header to recyclerView. Couldn't have different item type for first position, as library after reloading items caused recyclerview to scroll all way down to bottom of list.

I have created ViewHolder that holds my regular list item plus my header. This way my regular item was on position 0 with header, library stopped scrolling to bottom of recyclerView as first item was pagination's item aswell.